# getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--varName") does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, getcomputedstyle, getpropertyvalue

Well, I want to use some css vars in my js code.

Here is the part of my .css file and the .js code:

```js
const root = document.querySelector(":root");
const msgColor = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue("--msg-color");
console.log(msgColor);
```

```css
:root {
  --msg-color: crimson;
  --msg-text: floralwhite;
}
```

The problem is that in chrome, safari and the new Edge I'm getting right the color value in my constant, but in firefox, doesn't working.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: "_in chrome, firefox and the new Edge I'm getting right ... , but in firefox, doesn't working_" In which browser your code eventually "doesn't work"? (The code seems to work in FF77 as it is.)

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled.
In chrome, safari, and new edge is working. In firefox it does'nt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was the version of firefox. It was the 68.x.x
Now with the 77.0.1 works fine.